# Can't create new Bill with IDS V3

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I can't create new bill in QuickBooks Online using IDS V3. here is my request.

```
DEBUG com.intuit.logger  - Request URI : https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/RealmId/batch?requestid=567368a3b9fd45299418635cfc141316&
 DEBUG com.intuit.logger  - Http Method : POST
 DEBUG com.intuit.logger  - Request Body : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
        <IntuitBatchRequest xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
            <BatchItemRequest bId="1" operation="create">
                <Bill>
                    <DocNumber>1039</DocNumber>
                    <TxnDate>2013-12-24</TxnDate>
                    <PrivateNote></PrivateNote>
                    <Line>
                        <Description>12/24/2013: AU-Payroll Clearing: sdsdfdsf</Description>
                        <Amount>12.00</Amount>
                        <DetailType>AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail</DetailType>
                        <AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>
                            <CustomerRef type="Customer">14</CustomerRef>
                            <AccountRef type="Account">7</AccountRef>
                            <BillableStatus>Billable</BillableStatus>
                        </AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>
                    </Line>
                    <VendorRef type="Vendor">16</VendorRef>
                    <Memo></Memo>
                </Bill>
            </BatchItemRequest>
        </IntuitBatchRequest>
```

Here is the reply I got

```
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://internal.qdc.qbo.intuit.com/qbo22/v3/company/<realmId>/batch?requestid=567368a3b9fd45299418635cfc141316&amp;">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

Can someone help me ?
Thank you

Comment: 302 is a redirection message. I'd guess that you're using an outdated URL. It looks like the correct one is in the message you got.

Comment: What URL are you HTTP POSTing this request to?

Comment: Request URI : https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/realmId/batch?requestid=567368a3b9fd45299418635cfc141316&

Comment: I can read data with QB IDS V3 but I can't create new bill record

Comment: There are some issues in cluster 22. I'll update you as soon as it is fixed.

Comment: What are you getting back in the Location header of the 302 response?  Is it the same internal.qdc.qbo.intuit.com URL?

Comment: << "HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily[\r][\n]"
<< "Date: Tue, 24 Dec 2013 22:44:29 GMT[\r][\n]"
<< "Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)[\r][\n]"
<< "Location: https://internal.qdc.qbo.intuit.com/qbo22/v3/company/realmId/batch?requestid=567368a3b9fd45299418635cfc141316&[\r][\n]"
 << "Cache-Control: max-age=31536000[\r][\n]"
 << "Expires: Wed, 24 Dec 2014 22:44:30 GMT[\r][\n]"

Comment: I created an incident on intuit Support. the case number is 00008037.